# Noprocessor exception

Tags: java, exception, jmf

I'm trying to create a processor using the createprocessor method of JMF, i tried different formats of files (wmv, avi, mpg, mp4, MPEG) but still i have a Noprocessor Exception.
any help will be very appreciated
here is the code:

```
package org.jitsi.examples;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.format.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.codec.video.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.device.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.format.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.recording.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.rtp.translator.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.dtls.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.sdes.*;
import org.jitsi.impl.neomedia.transform.zrtp.*;
import org.jitsi.service.configuration.*;
import org.jitsi.service.libjitsi.*;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.*;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.codec.*;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.device.*;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.format.*;
import org.jitsi.service.neomedia.recording.*;
import org.jitsi.service.resources.*;
import org.jitsi.util.*;
import org.jitsi.util.event.*;
import org.jitsi.util.swing.*;
import org.json.simple.*;

import com.sun.media.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
/**
 *
 * @author Sami
 */
public class streamfromfile {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, NoDataSourceException, NoProcessorException {
        // TODO code application logic here

          URL dataurl = new File("C:\\Users\\Sami\\Desktop\\Project1.avi").toURI().toURL();

        Processor processor;
        MediaLocator medialoc = new MediaLocator(dataurl);
        processor = Manager.createProcessor(medialoc);
        if (processor != null)
        {
            System.out.print("this works !!");
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace too.